# SQL Server 2008 - INSERT for table working but UPDATE/DELETE hangs

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a dead simple stored procedure which only does an `INSERT` to a table.

The stored procedure takes several parameters (it's called from C# code) and does a simple insert.

Everything works fine with the insert - however, in some cases, there might be a PK violation, in which case I check the error code, and if there was a PK violation - then make an `UPDATE`.

After inserting the `UPDATE`, the stored procedure just hangs. It doesn't throw an error or anything.

I tried to replace the `UPDATE` with a `DELETE+INSERT` just to see if that would do anything, but it didn't.

The strangest part is - the code doesn't even reach the `UPDATE`!

I made sure that the IF statement is false and the problem still happens!

The C# code calls this stored procedure about every second. Even when the stored procedure hangs for a long time, after I comment out the `UPDATE` and update the stored procedure so that it only has the `INSERT` all of the rows get inserted. It's buffering them up somewhere, I guess.

I tried moving the `UPDATE` command to a different stored procedure and calling it (`EXEC updateSproc`) from the original stored procedure. This seemed to have solved the problem
at first glance, however, upon close inspection I could see that the update was still not working. I guess the only thing that happened is that the `updateSproc` was hanging instead of the original one - letting the C# code continue and inserting new values.

I tried updating and deleting from other tables from withing the original stored procedure and there was no problem.

It's as if this table is not allowing `UPDATE,DELETE`.

Everything is running as 'sa'

The table is not so large, about a million rows.

The fragmentation is OK. Page sizes are around 95% usage. Seems ok.

There is only 1 index (PK clustered) on the table - nothing fancy.

Any ideas?

### EDIT

I checked your proposals and this is what I got:

`exec sp_who2` returns:
`1529 05/12 17:39:27 .Net SqlClient Data Provider 53 0`

`dbcc INPUTBUFFER(53)` returns:
`RPC Event 0 TheDBName.dbo.AddInstrData;1`

`AddInstrData` is the stored procedure that is called. Inside it, there was a simple `INSERT` followed by an `UPDATE`.
Like I wrote before, I moved the `UPDATE` to a new stored procedure with only one command (the `UPDATE`).
So now, `AddInstrData` has an `INSERT` followed by an `EXEC UpdateInstrData`.
Before moving the `UPDATE` to a new stored procedure, data was not being inserted *at all*.
After moving it to the new stored procedure, data is being inserted properly - I'm guessing the hang just moved to the new stored procedure because I can see it in the Activity Monitor stuck on RUNNABLE and no updates are actually being performed.

Also, the SQL Server version is:
`Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1`

**Important Note:**
This problem doesn't always happen. Everything can work fine for a long time and suddenly it starts to happen. There might be a system time change but I think it has nothing to do with it.

### Edit 2

I tried placing the `UPDATE` back in the original stored procedure and I put it inside an `IF (1=0)` statement.
This still hangs! It's as if the mere presence of the `UPDATE` statement is causing the issue - it's in a block which is never actually executed.

**Important Note 2:**
If I open a new window in SMSS and do `EXEC AddInstrData` manually, the blockage stops and all the data that was queued (where is it queued?) is inserted into the table.

### New Progress

I think I've found the culprit!
It appears that things get stuck because of the following command (which is being executed even when the `UPDATE` isn't firing):

[image: SQL command that causes the hang]

The table name is obscured in the image - but this is the target table where I do the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on.

Any ideas?

Comment: The question does not have enough information to answer it. The reason I'm not closing it is that you have given a lot of information in general which is good. It appears you are suffering from a blocking problem. Execute `sp_who2` while the `UPDATE` is "hanging". You'll see which session is blocking the update by looking at the blocked-by column. Also, please post all relevant code.

Comment: are you really callin the sp every second?

Comment: +1 `usr`. After executing `sp_who2` use `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<BlkBy>)` to see what is executing the blocker session. Else, you could install `sp_WhoIsActive`([download](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx)) stored procedure (wrote by Adam Machanic) to get these information.

Comment: @meda Yes. the system is hardware-based, collection signals every second or so

Comment: @usr Does sp_who2 data show up in the Activity Monitor? Because in the Activity Monitor there seems to be nothing blocking. If not - I'll have access tomorrow and check your suggestion and Bogdan Sahlean's as well

Comment: You should share your code

Answer (score 0):

**Please check  foreign key in your table** with other table before DELETE
You can alter a foreign key constraint with delete cascade option as shown below. This will delete chind table rows related to master table rows when deleted.

```
ALTER TABLE MainTable
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_xyz  
FOREIGN KEY (xyz)  
REFERENCES ChildTable (xyz) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: He would be receiving an error if a FK was preventing the delete. In any case, guess-based answers are not that useful.

Comment: @Morteza The table has no Foreign Keys.

Comment: @thedude you can recreate the table and then check your logs.

Comment: @Morteza What should I be looking for? The problem is that this problem hardly ever occurs. This is a system which is active on numerous sites 24/7 but only happens once in a while. I wouldn't be able to recreate it.

Comment: @Morteza The `UPDATE` is very simple.  
I don't have it handy now but it's just basically:  
  
`IF (1=0)
BEGIN
UPDATE TheTable SET TheValue=@val WHERE TheDate=@date
END`  
The IF is false on purpose - just to demonstrate that this problem occurs even when the `UPDATE` never fires